# Get back the old tray in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, system-tray, xfce-panel

Is there a way to go back to *toggle the visibility of tray icons* in **Xubuntu** just as it was prior to 14.04 since now Unity indicators replaced the classic tray which I very much dislike because now one cannot show/hide certain apps.

I did a search in Synaptic but couldn't find such a package.

Answer (score 2):

You can selectively hide Unity indicators with the Indicator plugin.  Right click on the indicator plugin and select Properties.  You can toggle the Unity indicators independently, and completely disable application indicators in the same way.

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: This I know about and wasn't looking for, but thanks.

Comment: What I am mainly looking for is to be able to selectively toggle the visibility of all tray items, just like in KDE and how it was in Xubuntu in earlier versions. With the Unity indicator it's not possible the same way and if I toggle to hide all that won't be of any good either.